# How to place swiftlint config file in Swift Package?

Tags: ios, swift, swift-package-manager, swiftlint

In our app we are using cocoapods to keep our config file in a private repo and access the file in build phase like this

```
CONFIG_FILE="${PODS_ROOT}/My-Repo-Name/swiftlint.yml"
"${PODS_ROOT}/SwiftLint/swiftlint" --config $CONFIG_FILE
```

Now we are thinking of moving the config file to a swift package, can anyone help to determine how to give a path to the config file in the swift package?

Answer (score 1):

Bit of a hack, but you might be able to use:

```
CONFIG_FILE="${BUILD_DIR}/../../SourcePackages/checkouts/My-Repo-Name/swiftlint.yml"
```

Answer (score 0):

The above answer didn't work but this did

```
CONFIG_FILE="${BUILD_DIR%Build/*}SourcePackages/checkouts/<repo-name>/Sources/swiftlint.yml"
```